# Is it possible to set positive and negative buttons in a Dialog?

Tags: android, button, dialog

I have a Dialog in my android app and I want to set positive/negative buttons in the dialog. It is a Dialog, not an AlertDialog. I know that I could actually use an AlertDialog, but I would like to know, whether the same is possible within a dialog. If there is a possibility, I appreciate all of you for an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add anything you want in dialog. For an example

```
dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");


Button dialog_btn = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);
dialog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
{
    // TODO:
}
```

Here `custom_dialog` is a custom layout for dialog which has a button `dialog_button`. similarly you can add any widget and handle that.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there is another way to do it without creating buttons in a layout, like in AlertDialog.setPositiveButton! Thanks anyway!